# php language variables outside class in mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller, variables

I am trying to solve a tricky problem.

I am creating a project, which requires more than one language. So I have created files for all the languages, with an array of the language.

Now the problem is, I am using my own MVC system.

Basically, in my init file, I want to include a language file, which include the correct language, that works perfectly.

The problem appears, when I wanna show it in a view.

When I have my controller call the view class and render the view, it is in a class, making the variables outside the class unavailable.

I can solve this problem by including my language file, in the view renderer class, but since I sometimes need to set the variables in a model, its not working.

Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way is to make the language variable global: In your included language file, use

```
global $LANGUAGE;
$LANGUAGE=array(
  ...
);
```

and start your view methods with `global $LANGUAGE;` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try session for current selected language.